# Bound style not applying rapid updates to underlying value

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have this bound style:

```
<div :style="{height: errHeight}"
```

From this computed property:

```
errHeight() { return Math.ceil(this.errors.length * 20 + 7) + 'px'; }
```

`this.errors` refers to this computed property, from Vuex:

```
errors() { return this.$store.state.errors; },
```

Errors are added to the array using `array.push`. The style binding works fine when one error is added or removed, but on the initial page load there might be two or more errors added in quick succession by different asynchronous tasks failing (http requests), and in that case my errHeight() computed property only 
returns the height of 1 error.

**EDIT:**

If I move the height calculation into a watcher with a delay, it does work, so long as the delay is longer than the async functions that are affecting the height. `setTimeout(this.calcHeight, 1000);` not really a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

as it is `vuex` state, `errors.push` may not be triggering the change in computed property, You need to do following to make it work:

```
errors = [...errors, newError]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried it but it works the same as before. I only get the height of one error.

Comment: @daninthemix Can you add more code snippets or if possible create a fiddle?

Comment: I've tried, but I am completely unable to reproduce the problem on JSfiddle, as everything works fine, even when I nest the height changes in async functions. I'm at a loss. https://jsfiddle.net/1z7dskrq/1/

Comment: If I move the height calculation into a watcher with a delay, it does work, so long as the delay is long than the async functions that are affecting the height. `setTimeout(this.calcHeight, 1000);` not really a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @daninthemix It will be really helpful if you put more code, how are you updating?

Comment: As stated above, I am updating either with your method in the answer you posted, or with array.push. It doesn't matter - either method has the same result.

Comment: @daninthemix Sorry, I meant can you update the question with you code?

Comment: I have found a solution, of sorts, posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using setTimeout() to constrain how quickly new errors are written seems to work. Because in my CSS, the height transition takes 500ms, I don't think modifying the height again before that 500ms is up works. So I need this code to ensure the array doesn't change twice within 500ms:

```
error(context, error) {
    var d = context.state.lastError;
    if (d === null || d < (Date.now() - 500)) {
        context.commit('error', error);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            context.commit('error', error);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```